# ASP MVC 3, generation of tables fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Edited:**

i'm trying to learn ASP MVC, but i'm having a problem, the Web Developer Express is failing to generate the database tables.

Please How i know where is the problem?

-
i'm just [following the asp mvc website tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application), and there the model class "make - create" the database + tables just pressing F5.... in my first tutorial all was perfect... but now i don't know what's happening

Thanks you guys :)

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more details regarding what you've done, where it's failing, and what error you're getting.

Comment: There's the problem, the Visual Web Developer say nothing....

Comment: The DataBase is without tables :(, just that, no error, nothing else

Comment: Yes, but what steps have you taken? I personally have never expected Web Developer Express to generate my database tables for me, so I don't know where you're coming from. Explain what you've done, and at what point it's not behaving the way you expect. If I said "Microsoft Word isn't saving my file," you'd need more information before you could help me figure out what I need to do differently, right?

Comment: @Asinox: Have you tried adding a table to the database to see what happens?

Comment: mmmm, thanks you for reply, in just following the asp mvc website tutorial, and there the model class "make - create" the database + tables just pressing F5....

I don't know how your work, maybe your advanced, but im creating the database + tables with my models class like say the tutorials.... in my first tutorial all was perfect... but now i don't know what's happening

Sorry with my english

Comment: @Asinox: Your English is better than my Spanish: I'm in no position to complain. ;-)  Please edit your question to include the information you added in your comment. Provide links to the tutorial you're trying to run, and describe in detail the steps that you have taken, and which step is failing.

Comment: Thanks you StriplingWarrior, edited :)

Comment: Make sure you have made the changes that the article specifies for the `Global.asax.cs` file, then set a breakpoint on the Application_Start method. Debug your application. Does the debugger stop at your breakpoint? Can you "step into" the `SchoolInitializer.Seed` method, and verify that it is being run?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created a database you'll need to tell the app that you want to drop and recreate the tables when the database changes. Try adding this to Global.asax

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourApp.Models.YourAppContext>());
```